# Question on Euler's Theorem on Homogeneous Functions

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Show that, if $f$ is differentiable and homogeneous of degree $k$, then the tangent hyperplane to $f(x)=1$ at $x=a$ is $\sum_{i=1}^n$$\frac{\partial f(a)}{\partial x_i}x_i$ $= k$

I understand that as a homogeneous function of degree $k$, then by Euler's Theorem on homogeneous functions:

$\sum_{i=1}^n$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}x_i$ $= kf$ and I can prove this.

But I'm not sure how to define the tangent hyperplane. I would have thought that the equation would be given by

$\nabla f(a)\bullet (x-a) = 0$

Can anybody help? Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis appears to be correct to me. Your equation for the tangent hyperplane is
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial f(a)}{\partial x_i}(x_i-a_i)=0.$$
Rewrite this as
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial f(a)}{\partial x_i}x_i=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial f(a)}{\partial x_i}a_i=kf(a)=k.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems obvious now that you pointed it out. Thanks. Best.